# Media Library empty after server move (exact copy of files and db's)

Tags: media, media-library, migration

After exactly copying both all the files and the database of a site over from an old server to a new one with the same URL (granted, DNS has not been switched over yet but not sure if that has any influence on this), the media library shows up empty, and with it breaks a few plugins that seem to be reliant thereupon. I checked and the files/images are located still in the same directory, `wp-content/uploads`, the only thing that changed is the root folder went from `/public_html/site.com/` to `/var/www/clientx/web`. One extra thing, the "Add From Server" plugin just blank-screens after a long while loading not showing any files to import, and when in the media library the "loading" animation at the middle of the action bar just keeps spinning, as if it keeps scanning or glitches...?

How would one go about diagnosing where the underlying problem is located and how to fix that?